# How to make a for loop scanner code go down in a set amount of number?

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

How to make a for loop scanner code go down in a set amount of number?
For instance, type in 30 and then type in 3 and then it goes down like 30, 27, 24, 21, etc.

This is what I have so far. I want int y to represent how many are taken down at a time.

```
import java.util.Scanner; // ...

public class b
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    int x,y;

    Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("how many  bottles hanging on the wall");

    x = scannerObject.nextInt();
    System.out.println("how many  bottles are taken down the wall");

    y = scannerObject.nextInt();
    for (int counter = x; counter > 0; counter--)
    {
      if (counter == 1)
      {
        System.out.println(" " + counter + "  bottle hanging on the wall");
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println(" " + counter + "  bottles hanging on the wall");
      }

      System.out.println("And if one  bottle should accidently fall, ");
    }

    System.out.println("No  bottles hanging on the wall");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `x = x - y;` inside the for loop. This would make `x` represent the number of bottles currently hanging on the wall, i.e., `x` would be decremented with 3 each iteration given your example.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your for loop with:

```
for (int counter = x; counter > 0; counter-=y)
```

That should give you the desired output.

The `counter-=y` change is equivalent to `counter=counter-y`